# How to upload Metadata to arweave at backend using solana metaplex js sdk?

Tags: metaplex, metaplex-js

I have tried uploading metadata to arweave from the frontend using the `metaplex.nfts().uploadMetadata` and it is working great. I would like to know if it is possible to upload from the backend using `metaplex.nfts().uploadMetadata` and privateKey. If possible please share an example code or docs for the same.

Thank You

**edit: I tried something like this.**

```
const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl('devnet'));
  const metaplex = new Metaplex(connection);
  const key = Uint8Array.from(
    base58.decode('PrivateKey'),
  );

  const keypair = Keypair.fromSecretKey(key);
  console.log(`keypair created: ${keypair.publicKey.toString()}`);

  metaplex.use(walletAdapterIdentity(keypair));
  metaplex.use(
    bundlrStorage({
      address: 'https://devnet.bundlr.network',
      providerUrl: 'https://api.devnet.solana.com',
      timeout: 60000,
    }),
  );
```

Which obviously threw an error saying `The current wallet adapter does not support the following operation: [signTransaction].` How do I solve this?

**edit: I think I solved it**
Just have to update the bundlrStorage to use the keypair generated from the private key

```
metaplex.use(
    bundlrStorage({
      address: 'https://devnet.bundlr.network',
      providerUrl: 'https://api.devnet.solana.com',
      timeout: 60000,
      identity: keypair,
    }),
```

Comment: Hey! Can you post the error which you're facing when you try to upload the metadata to Arweave via the backend?

Comment: Hey Mukesh, I dont have any error. I want to know how I can use my wallet private key on backed to upload the metadata using `metaplex.nfts().uploadMetadata`.

Thanks

Comment: Hey Mukesh, I tried something now and have an error now, please take a look at the edited question.

Comment: correction: It is solved now 

Comment: Glad that you have figured it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting it here to close the topic.

```
const key = Uint8Array.from(
    base58.decode('PrivateKey'), // converting private key to bs58 array
  );

  const keypair = Keypair.fromSecretKey(key);

  metaplex.use(walletAdapterIdentity(keypair));metaplex.use(
    bundlrStorage({
      address: 'https://devnet.bundlr.network',
      providerUrl: 'https://api.devnet.solana.com',
      timeout: 60000,
      identity: keypair,
    }),
```